# Installing Zend on a Plesk Shared Host

Tags: zend-framework, shared-hosting

I've created an Zend Application on a local machine, with Zend Server Installed on it.

However I am now looking to migrate it to a live host - Shared hosting with Parallel Plesk 8.4.0

I've moved everything up and at one point I was just getting a blank screen when loading the public folder.

I tweaked the public/index.php file to include Error_Reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT)

So I am now getting an error from the script. The error I am getting is...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'Error parsing /var/www/vhosts/eekonomics.co.uk/httpdocs/application/configs/application.ini on line 4
```

Theres more to the error. But alot of it seems irrelevant, If required I can post the rest.

Has anyone any ideas how I can get this setup and working, Its slowing me down big style :-(

Any help appreciated...

Comment: I've managed to fix this. By changing APPLICATION_PATH to the absolute path in the application.ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the application.ini file from APPLICATION_PATH to the absolute path of the files seems to have fixed this.

I've got another error associated with PDO Adapter not being installed, but that is down to a server install issue rather than Zend / PHP.